# Restricting outgoing mail to some domains in Exim (with Debian-specific configuration method)

Tags: linux, debian, exim

I have some Debian-based VMs that are supposed to hand over mail to a central host (smarthost/satellite).

This is only meant for locally-generated mail received over localhost or `sendmail` command, but with a twist: *I do not want local VMs to be able to send mail to the internet, just to some designated domains.* (kind of like preventing open relay for localhost).

I would have used ssmtp were it not for the fact that it does not listen on normal SMTP ports on localhost, so I'm using Exim.

I'm using `update-exim4.conf`:

```
% cat update-exim4.conf.conf 

dc_eximconfig_configtype='satellite'
dc_other_hostnames=''
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1 ; ::1'
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains='mydomain1.com ; mydomain2.net'
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost='mailsrv1.mydomain2.net:mailsrv2.mydomain2.net'
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname='false'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='maildir_home'
```

I have this in local macros:

```
% cat exim4.conf.localmacros 
CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_ACL_FILE = /etc/exim4/local_CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_ACL_FILE.conf
```

Relevant ACL snippet:

```
% cat local_CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_ACL_FILE.conf 
deny
    message  = relay not permitted
    log_message = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    !domains = mydomain1.com : mydomain2.net
```

Now the problem is that `CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_ACL_FILE` gets included after `accept` to relay and local domains, so the `acl_smtp_rcpt` completes before it reaches my local macro.

Sure, I can replace entire `acl_smtp_rcpt` with `MAIN_ACL_CHECK_RCPT`, but I do not want to do that - I'd have to copy the existing `acl_smtp_rcpt` section and what if on future upgrade it goes out of sync with newly autogenerated config?